# Laravel read json from database

Tags: json, laravel

I'm trying to read and output a json from database. I insert a json using something like this:

```
        $widget->settings = json_encode($input->get('settings'));
```

Then when I read I try with:

```
        $settings = json_decode($response->settings);
```

However I get an escaped string and not a valid json. This is what I got:

```
"settings":"{\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.google.com\"}"
```

But I was expecting something like:

```
"settings":{"url":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}
```

[EDIT]

I've tried also to add this to my model:

```
public function getSettingsAttribute()
{
    return (array)json_decode($this->settings);
}
```

But I got error:

```
Undefined property: Widget::$settings
```

Comment: Check if you didn't escaped/encoded it twice. Just try to parse/decode it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this solve the problem:

```
public function getSettingsAttribute($value)
{   
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this with the success text:

```
    return response()->json(array("notification" => "success", "data" => json_decode($yourdata->info)));
```